# Is there a shorter way of using the ternary conditional operator in Perl?

Tags: perl, conditional-operator

I want to do the following assignment if possible in one line and without having it really long:

```
my $variable = defined($self->{_some_thing_stored_here}) ? $self->{_some_thing_stored_here} : new some_function(@with_some_parameters);
```

Is it possible somehow in a similar way to getting variables in a loop with "$_" to get the parameter of the if condition, so that it looks somehow like this:

```
my $variable = defined($self->{_some_thing_stored_here}) ? $_ : new some_function(@with_some_parameters);
```

PD: I know it is possible to put the condition in a variable, but I'd like to know if is possible to do it shorter.

Comment: The operator in question is called the conditional operator. It is but one of many ternary operators. Fixed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [defined-or operator](https://perldoc.pl/perlop#Logical-Defined-Or):

```
my $variable = $self->{_some_thing_stored_here} // some_function(@with_some_parameters);
```

Requires Perl 5.10+.

You can also (ab)use [postfix foreach](https://perldoc.pl/perlsyn#Statement-Modifiers) to make use of `$_` when the defined check isn't exactly what you need, though it's not the most common idiom, and you should take care not to declare variables with postfix statement modifiers, and that you don't call anything which will modify the now-aliased global `$_`.

```
my $variable;
$variable = check($_) ? $_ : something_else() for $self->{_some_thing_stored_here};
# make sure something_else does not clobber $_
# that would also clobber $self->{_some_thing_stored_here} !
```